# semgentation fault because of strlen while sorting string matrix with qsort

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b) {
    size_t fa = strlen((const char *)a);
    size_t fb = strlen((const char *)b);
    return (fa > fb) - (fa < fb);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  FILE* dict;
  char** dictionary,ch;
  int max_w_length=0,w_length,n_lines;
  if ((dict = fopen("Words1.txt", "r+")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error with given dictionary!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  while((ch=getc(dict))!=EOF){
    if (ch!='\n') w_length++;
    else {
      n_lines++;
      if (w_length>max_w_length) max_w_length=w_length;
      w_length=0;
    }
  }
  printf("%d\n",max_w_length );
  rewind(dict); //return to the beggining of the dictionary file
  if ((dictionary=malloc(n_lines*sizeof(int*)))==NULL){ 
    printf("Not enough memory!\n");
    return 1;
  }
    for(int i=0;i<n_lines;i++){
      if((dictionary[i]=malloc(max_w_length*sizeof(int)))==NULL){  
        printf("Not enough memory for the crossword!\n");
        return 1;
      }
      fgets(dictionary[i],max_w_length,dict);     
    }

    qsort(dictionary,n_lines,max_w_length,compare);
    for(int i=0;i<n_lines;i++){
      printf("%s\n",dictionary[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compliling I get no warnings, but I get a segmentation fault while executing. When I run it with gdb debugger i get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:62
62  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
```

Any ideas for that?

Comment: Where did you get that there were lines-1 items of length 10?

Comment: Read the documentation for `qsort`. Second argument is the number of elements in your array, which you have correct at `n_lines-1`. But the 3rd argument is the *size of an element*. What is an element? It is a pointer to `char` (a `char *`). What's the size of one of those? `sizeof(char *)`. Not 10. On a related note, I don't understand why you assigned: `dictionary=malloc(n_lines*sizeof(int*))`. That should be `sizeof(char *)` not `sizeof(int *)`, although the values are the same. And this is strange: `dictionary[i]=malloc(max_w_length*sizeof(int))`. Where does `int` come into play here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3):

You're not passing the correct element size to `qsort`:

```
                       //  v------- here
qsort(dictionary,n_lines-1,max_w_length ,compare);
```

Each element of your array is a `char *`, not an array of size `max_w_length`,  so use the size of that:

```
qsort(dictionary,n_lines-1,sizeof(char *),compare);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790276/2410359) good answer identifies a problem: OP used the incorrect element size: `size` argument for `qsort(base, nmemb, size, compar)`.
2. Code did not allocate space for a `'\n'` nor a string's *null character*.
3. Code used the wrong type in allocating.
4. Brittle line count and line length calculation.

Rather than try to use the size of the *type*, use the size of the referenced data.  This is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// qsort(dictionary,n_lines,max_w_length,compare);
// qsort(dictionary,n_lines,sizeof (char *),compare);
qsort(dictionary, n_lines, sizeof *dictionary, compare);
// or 
qsort(dictionary, n_lines, sizeof dictionary[0], compare);
```

This idiom can be applied to `malloc()` also.

```
//                                        
// if ((dictionary=malloc(n_lines*sizeof(int*)))==NULL){ 
if ((dictionary=malloc(n_lines * sizeof *dictionary)) == NULL){ 

  //                                                v-- wrong type
  // if((dictionary[i]=malloc(max_w_length*sizeof(int)))==NULL){  
  if((dictionary[i]=malloc(max_w_length*sizeof dictionary[i][0])) == NULL){  

  // Use +2 to allocate needed string space
  if((dictionary[i]=malloc((max_w_length+2)*sizeof dictionary[i][0])) == NULL){  

  // fgets(dictionary[i],max_w_length,dict);
  fgets(dictionary[i], max_w_length + 2, dict);
```

As [@lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790201/semgentation-fault-because-of-strlen-while-sorting-string-matrix-with-qsort/48791466#comment84582490_48790201) commented, malloc used a type mis-matched point with `int *`, rather than `char *`.  Rarely are these of different size, but *could* be.  By using `sizeof *dictionary`, the type is moot as `sizeof *dictionary` is correct, regardless of what type it points to.

---

OP's method of calculating line count and max line length fails should the last *line* of the file not end with a `'\n'`.

Alternative

```
int ch;  // use int, not char
int previous = '\n';
while((ch=getc(dict)) != EOF){
  if (previous == '\n') {
    n_lines++;
  }
  w_length++;
  if (w_length>max_w_length) {
    max_w_length = w_length;
  }
  if (ch == '\n') {
    w_length = 0;
  }
  previous = ch;
}
```

This `max_w_length` includes the `'\n'` and so `max_w_length + 1` needed to allocate to save a *String* that can hold it.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for your answers, so my code now looks like that:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b) {
    size_t fa = strlen((const char *)a);
    size_t fb = strlen((const char *)b);
    return (fa > fb) - (fa < fb);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  FILE* dict;
  char** dictionary;
  int max_w_length=0,w_length,n_lines;
  if ((dict = fopen("Words.txt", "r+")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error with given dictionary!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  int ch;  
  int previous = '\n';
  while((ch=getc(dict)) != EOF){
    if (previous == '\n') {
      n_lines++;
    }
    w_length++;
    if (w_length>max_w_length) {
      max_w_length = w_length;
    }
    if (ch == '\n') {
      w_length = 0;
    }
    previous = ch;
  }
  printf("%d\n",max_w_length );
  rewind(dict); //return to the beggining of the dictionary file
  if ((dictionary=malloc(n_lines*sizeof(char*)))==NULL){ //allocate space for the dictionary
    printf("Not enough memory!\n");
    return 1;
  }
    for(int i=0;i<n_lines;i++){
      if((dictionary[i]=malloc(max_w_length*sizeof(char)))==NULL){  //allocate space for the dictionary
        printf("Not enough memory!\n");
        return 1;
      }
      fgets(dictionary[i],max_w_length+2,dict);      //put the words in to the dictionary
    }

    qsort(dictionary,n_lines,sizeof(*dictionary),compare);
    for(int i=0;i<n_lines;i++){
      printf("%s",dictionary[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so i dont get a segmentation, but when i run it the programm soes not sortt the words by their length, it doesnt do anything at all. Whtat could possibly be wrong?